# How to copy and paste Seed from passwordmanager to light wallet

Tags: security, wallet, seed, address

To confuse a keylogger I don't copy and paste the whole seed into the light wallet, but only part of it and the next part I write by myself before copy and past the next part and so on. Or I write more than 81 letters in the password manager and copy and paste the whole password to the light wallet and delete the parts that are wrong inside the light wallet. 
The address I find inside the seed I use for sending only 1 IOTA in first step. After that I log in again to check if this 1 IOTA really did arrive. If so I can send the whole amount I wanted to send to that same address and I am sure it will arrive in the correct wallet.
Now my question:
Has anyone a better idea to not make the fatal mistake of sending money to the wrong address? Because that would be the worst scenario... I guess you will never find the correct seed if you did send the money to the wrong address...

This problem of course only occurs if I log into a seed that only shows one address. But that's exactly where I store my main amount of money because I don't want to log in with this seed anymore until I sell (because I am afraid of keylogger). So the problem of sending to wrong address would be fatal...

Comment: Since both questions are from you, what's the difference from your point of view?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use your wallet on a computer where you fear keyloggers. If you're not sure about your secure computer, don't use any cryptocurrencies.

Comment: While that's a correct sentiment it's more of a comment than a proper answer to the question.